# Android Chrome Custom Tabs Deep Link Redirect in OAuth flow 'cancelled'

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs, android-deep-link

I am debugging why I am seeing a "(canceled)" status in chrome custom tabs when redirect to deep link is sent using a custom scheme.  ie `myapp://app/path?foo=bar`

The activity in my manifest is as follows:

The reason I started to debug is that I have found one case in which the redirect to the deep link is sent and the Android app/activity is not opened.  When debugging I noticed that the redirect from my server shows a canceled status.

[image]

The redirect is coming from a nodejs server using express.  I have tried sending the redirect in a couple of different ways, with the same result.

```
res.redirect(302, 'myapp://app/path?foo=bar');
```

and

```
res.status(302);
res.header('Location', 'myapp://app/path?foo=bar');
res.end();
```

In most cases the redirect, even though chrome custom tabs says its canceled still deep links to the Android application and opens the correct activity.

Should I be concerned about seeing a canceled status, even for the working cases?

If the canceled status is not of concern, any ideas on why in some cases the application/activity would not be opened when the deep link is sent?  I have dug around for some time and have seen a number of issues with navigation being blocked by chrome and chrome custom tabs.  Like this:

["Navigation is blocked" when redirecting from Chrome Custom Tab to Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524087/navigation-is-blocked-when-redirecting-from-chrome-custom-tab-to-android-app)

However this usually points to an older version of chrome and chrome custom tabs.  Any help or ideas into how I can debug why the deep link would not open the application.

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: @lostintranslation any luck?